# Vaadin Maven Repo and Artifactory

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, artifactory

I developed an  java web-app application with  spring and vaadin, in this application, I  used some addons like easyuploads and wizards-for-vaadin. Then i added the following configuration in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
    <artifactId>easyuploads</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
    <artifactId>wizards-for-vaadin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Add-On Repository -->
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>vaadin-addons</id>
    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Now I'm installing artifactory (for the first time) like tool of repository managment and I thought to add a remote repository for the vaadin-addons. But this not work:

[image]

How can I solve it ?
Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their repository is not browsable, that's why you get the 404 on testing. You can disregard the error, if should resolve the artifacts just fine (assuming the coordinates are correct).

Answer (score 4):

We found out by accident that there seems to exist a browsable Nexus repository now: http://vaadin.com/nexus/content/repositories/vaadin-addons/

We have successfully included it as a proxy repository in our local Nexus installation.